# Rhino 1.7.14 supports ES6 functionalities like promises, but I am not able to use VERSION_ES6 flag

Tags: java, ecmascript-6, promise, es6-promise, rhino

It is mentioned in Rhino 1.7.14 as Rhino can support ES6 features if VERSION_ES6 flag is used.

[Flag to be used in Rhino 1.7.14](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xLEYl.png)

But there were no clear documentation of how & where to use the flag

I tried to use the Context.VERSION_ES6 flag to setLanguageVersion. [https://github.com/workcraft/workcraft/issues/1367](https://stackoverflow.com) 
But it didn't help me.

Am I trying the flag in a correct way ? Or should it be used in some other place ?

is there any other approach to make promises work in Rhino ?

I expect to unleash all the features of ES6 they can be provided by Rhino 1.7.14

Answer (score 0):

I got it working on the parser with:

```
CompilerEnvirons compilerEnvirons = new CompilerEnvirons();
compilerEnvirons.setLanguageVersion(Context.VERSION_ES6);
```

but I don't execute it. If you need to run the code finding where you can pass this environs must not be too difficult.